# Obtain the Filename for the Current Running SQL script - MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a system that auto-generates SQL files for me in the format:

CALLID_DATE_SCRIPTYPE.sql - eg *108312_20170913_DeleteRubbishData.sql*

I want to grab the **call id** and **current user** automatically without having to specify it again.

I know how to grab user, but not sure if it is possible to grab filename.

Anyone know if this is possible?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
DECLARE @File NVARCHAR(100) = CURRENTFILENAMEORWHATEVERTHEFUNCTIONISCALLED();
DECLARE @AuditData NVARCHAR(100) = 'Call: ' + LEFT(@File, CHARINDEX('_', @File) - 1) 
                               + ', User: ' + SUSER_NAME();
PRINT @AuditData
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Call: 108312, User: Sys\JSmith
```

Comment: You mean if you are in SQL Server Management Studio executing a script, you want to output the script's filename?

Comment: Did you try it? It's just a matter of parsing the file name. But that file name is not inherently available to the database engine during execution  - whatever application is used to run that script (ssms, sqlcmd, etc.) will have to provide it. Better yet, simply add logic to the process that creates the script to embed that information in the script in some fashion.

Comment: @SMor - Thanks, suspected this wasn't possible, but couldn't find a "Nope, you can't do that" anywhere. If you repost what you've said as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as THE answer (especially if you can reference something to back up what you say). :)

Comment: @TT - yes that is correct

Comment: Looking this issue up online, I'm seeing several answers that also claim that this isn't possible ([example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/095e9ce3-a2fc-463a-b64d-0bab18be8c31/can-you-get-the-file-name-of-the-current-executing-tsql-script?forum=transactsql))